# Is it possible to add your own tags to a GPX file like in XML?

Tags: xml, gpx

I know GPX is a light-weight XML data format but what I want to know is it possible to add my own tag like `<Town> Some Town here </Town>` which will hold the nearest town that the GPS data was done near or would I have to save this in a seperate XML file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the gpx types, including [`<gpx/>`](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#element_gpx) itself, have have something called `<extensions/>`. Extensions can hold any xml content you want. The only requirement is that what you put in there is linked to a different schema. Therefor it's required to use a namespace for your tags.

You can put something like `<myns:town>Some town here</myns:town>` in there assuming you define the myns namespace in the top.

- You can read more about this in the Gpx specs [here](http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/#type_extensionsType)
- Garmin uses extensions extensively. To get an idea how they do it you can get their schema [here](http://www8.garmin.com/xmlschemas/GpxExtensionsv3.xsd)